# jQuery replace image source in a list with next one, and start over at the end

Tags: jquery, image, replace, slider, attr

I have set of images, and need to replace their source with next one. 
I managed to do that, but how to make it to loop infinite, 
so last image should get source of first image, etc.
I - 1,2,3,4,5
II - 2,3,4,5,1
III - 3,4,5,1,2
etc.
And I have
I - 1,2,3,4,5
II- 2,3,4,5,5
III - 3,4,5,5,5
etc.
I tried something with clone, but I can't clone it forever.
Here is fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/lima_fil/q7vtG/3/

```
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slider-image">
            <a href="#"><img src="image1.jpg" title="Title 1 " alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <div class="slider-image">
            <a href="#"><img src="image2.jpg" title="Title 2 " alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And jQuery

```
//Clone all slides - so that last image have next image
    $('.slide').clone().appendTo('.slider').addClass('slide-hidden');   

        var interval = setInterval(function(Slajder){
            $(".slide").each(function( index ) {
                var index2 = index + 1;
// Replace Current Image with next Image
                $('.slide:nth-child(' + index + ') img').attr('src', $('.slide:nth-child(' + index2 + ') img').attr('src'));
            });
        }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
var index2 = (index % 5) + 1;
```

so that if index is 5, it goes to 1

Comment: Sorry dystroy i see the problem was OP using jsfiddle with 4 elements, not 5. I removed previous comment